# PowerBI - concatenate column values ​in measure

Tags: powerbi

i need concatenate column values (B) ​​in measure

Table1:

```
A   B
1   RED
2   GREEN
3   BlUE
4   RED
5   BLACK
```

in measure = RED GREEN BLUE RED BLACK

How can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [CONCATENATEX()](https://dax.guide/concatenatex/) function.

Here is a simple example:

```
B values = 
    CONCATENATEX(
        VALUES('Table'[B]),
        'Table'[B],
         " "
)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Wow that's brilliant @NickKrasnov!